# How might I perform DNS lookups using C/C++ on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, smtp, dns

How do I get similar functionality to the `host` command using a c api (or any other language for that matter)? I need more information than just an IP address given by `gethostbyname()`; specifically, the SMTP-related data.

Comment: When you mention *smtp-related*, do you mean the MX record for a domain?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093410/pulling-mx-record-from-dns-server and several otehrs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If a blocking (synchronous) query is ok, just use [`res_query()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/res_query), and link your program with -lresolv.

```
 len = res_query(host, C_IN, T_MX, &answer, sizeof(answer));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [FireDNS](http://directory.fsf.org/project/FireDNS/). It's a very fast C library for all kinds of dns queries.

Comment: The project looks abandonned (last release in 2004) and unfortunately the download link doesn't work (http://www.firestuff.org/)...

Answer (score 1):

I like [adns](http://www.gnu.org/software/adns/) because it allows for asynchronous requests

Comment: ps, I prefer like the FireDns, because it much easier and clearer :D

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old, but I have long searched a dns library, and all answers here just stubs me. I think libraries like adns/udns have written not for human beings. And FireDNS for a long time have not working download links.

I have found [poslib](http://freecode.com/projects/poslib) as the best dns library with very easy interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a function in the C standard library for this, but many scripting languages do have this functionality 'built in'. For example, Perl has the [`Net::DNS`](http://www.net-dns.org/docs/Net/DNS.html) package:

```
use Net::DNS;
my @mx = mx("example.com");
foreach $host (@mx) {
  print $host;
}
```

If you need to do this in C, a quick google shows up a few C libraries out there which you can use:

- [adns](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~ian/adns/)
- [udns](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/udns.html)
- [dns.c](http://www.25thandclement.com/~william/projects/dns.c.html)
- [FireDNS](http://directory.fsf.org/project/FireDNS/) (as mentioned by ko-dos)

Answer (score 0):

And I would add, unless you're writing a mail relay you almost certainly shouldn't be looking up MX records - you should be passing the mail on to a user-configured mail relay instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try c-ares library https://c-ares.haxx.se/, which allows to send asynchronous DNS queries. It also comes with adig - its own version of dig utility for querying DNS. You can check it to see how to parse DNS reply: [adig.c source](https://github.com/c-ares/c-ares/blob/master/adig.c)