# Querying custom DNS Server using C

Tags: c, winapi, dns

I want to make a DNS query to my own DNS server instead the default one.

Which api can I use to do that ?

I know getaddrinfo (which ping.exe using), but how can i make this function query my dns server, instead the default one ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [adns](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/adns) resolver library.

Another option is to use the [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) library, which works on Windows and allows you to use alternative nameservers.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted. Both these APIs will allow you to query alternative nameservers (as opposed to using the system resolver). An explanation along with the down-vote will help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

- [Code to do a direct DNS lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907528/code-to-do-a-direct-dns-lookup)
- [How might I perform DNS lookups using C/C++ on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128409/how-might-i-perform-dns-lookups-using-c-c-on-linux)