# Best way to resolve a DNS TXT record on Linux/Unix/Posix/BSD type systems?

Tags: c, unix, sockets, network-programming, dns

I want to write some portable (as possible) C code to look up DNS TXT records. I would also prefer not to have dependencies on libraries that don't ship with the machine.

What is the best way to do this on Unix-like machines using standard libraries?

I found some sample code that works using libresolv, but it's not reentrant (not thread safe) and is very ugly. Is there a better way?

Also, what about Windows? If there were a way that worked there too that would be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [res_query](http://linux.die.net/man/3/res_query) which uses the standard libresolv.

There's an [example here](http://www.codase.com/search/display?file=L2dlbnRvbzIvdmFyL3RtcC9yZXBvcy9jb2Rhc2UuYy9jbGFtYXYtMC44Ni4yL3dvcmsvY2xhbWF2LTAuODYuMi9mcmVzaGNsYW0vZG5zLmM=&lang=c&off=1411+1459+) from clamav:

```
if((len = res_query(domain, C_IN, T_TXT, answer, PACKETSZ)) < 0) {
  mprintf("@Can't query %s\n", domain);
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of code that I found. You then have to parse the answer quite a bit.

But it's not reentrant. If you used it from multiple threads, you would have to surround it with a static mutex.

There are reentrant calls for getting A, AAAA, and CNAME addresses via getaddrinfo() and pals. I was curious if there's anything I don't know that does something similar for TXT records.

Answer (score 1):

This is a FAQ. See [Code to do a direct DNS lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907528/code-to-do-a-direct-dns-lookup) or [How might I perform DNS lookups using C/C++ on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128409/how-might-i-perform-dns-lookups-using-c-c-on-linux).